# Where is the crow

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I am having a real issue with hunting this bird down, and i'm actually beginning to think my game may have possible glitched.

I found the bird more-or-less straight away but then it flew away. I've hunted high and low for it, day and night and I cannot find it anywhere. I've looked in all the places that have been mentioned in other answers but still got nothing.

Has this happened to anybody else? Does it go anywhere in Soviet Instillation or just around the main 'mill' area?

Comment: Keep using your survival senses and look for that green circle, kill it as soon as you see it. You may have to fast travel to another area and then back in to reset it. I found mine on a wire over one of the gates.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Survival Instincts the green concentric circles around the messenger bird will appear. If you do not see these circles, even after fast traveling away and then back to the Soviet Installation, then you probably experienced a bug that was fixed in Patch 3.

Patch 3 was released on January 22, 2016. You can read the patch notes [here](http://forums.eu.square-enix.com/showthread.php?t=182991), specifically

> Fixed an issue with the Misguided Intelligence quest where the messenger bird would despawn and not return.

I experienced the same issue as you and after patching on January 22, the bird appeared.